# Being chosen, however, is probably not enough, passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, fused-determiner

May this get discerned passive voice?

> *Being chosen, however, is probably not enough.*

*Being*, a participle verb, that goes to a gerund noun phrase *Being chosen* (and this may customarily seem [a thing done], an object)?

And in ***Being chosen***, however, is probably not enough, what may customarily go as a thing done, an object, gets placed in a subject place in passive voice? So *Being chosen* gets discerned a subject of *is* and *probably not enough*, an object of *is* (in passive voice)? I may not get how to discern *however*, (maybe a "parenthetical"?), and in *probably not enough*, I think someone did text that there seemed a "fused determiner" here?

Answer (score 1):

The gerund clause *being chosen* is indeed in the passive voice. Its Subject (the Patient, the person or persons who are chosen) is inferred from the context.

But this clause is not an *independent* clause—it cannot stand by itself as a sentence. Only clauses with *finite* verbs can be independent. (Finite verbs are those which are inflected for tense, and sometimes person and number. Infinitives, past/passive participles, and gerund-participles are **non**finite.)

The main clause **does** have a finite verb and it can stand by itself as a sentence: *X is not enough*. The gerund clause acts as the Subject of the main clause, *X*. What is not enough? *Being chosen* is not enough.

The main clause is in the active voice. Copulative *BE* does not take objects, only predicate complements; it cannot be cast in the passive voice, even though as an auxiliary it is a necessary component of the passive construction.

As you conjecture, *however* is a kind of "parenthetical". It is not a **constituent** of the sentence, a piece which is necessary to "constitute" the sentence, but an **adjunct**—something added.

In some contexts *enough* acts unambiguously as a "fused determiner", but here it is very difficult to detect a head with which *enough* has been fused. I'd see it as an adjectival. But whatever else it may be, it is certainly a predicative complement of *is*, which is all that is relevant to your question.

Comment: So gerund clause *being chosen* goes in passive voice. Finite and nonfinite verbs seems like interesting new information to me. I thank you. Maybe, it all together gets dictated a complete sentence? Things like auxiliary I may not get. It seems like a passive dependent gerund noun phrase a thing maybe customarily done or thing done to in a subject place. I guess I may think it like a patient, maybe, like (you, them, some person and or maybe thing[?]) maybe united into *being chosen*.

Comment: I guess *be* in *being chosen*, a copulative here and maybe an auxiliary to *being **chosen*** gerund phrase? So *however* a parenthetical, or (adjunct). I may not get a grammatical function of *head*. And I guess *probably not enough*, predicative complement. I think some did text subject complement?  I may get predicative complement. *Probably not enough*, object, predicative complement, *enough* adjective(?). I think I got abundant information here. I thank you, StoneyB.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you for an answer, I was in other question very confused about the complement. I thought *"probably not enough"* is a  subject complement, because it is telling something about the subject *"being chosen"*. Can you please tell how to determine if it's a subject complement or just a complement of the verb as is the case here.